# App Tracking Transparency implementation for a iOS app based on a WebView

Tags: ios, webview, privacy, idfa, apptrackingtransparency

I did many researches on the web but I did not find a clear answer to doubts.

I need to publish an update for my **iOS** app.
Now it is mandatory that app implements **App Tracking Transparency** if the App privacy section states that the application is collecting data information.

My app consists in a WebView showing some pages of a web site.
All tracking about user information (technical cookie, third party, etc..) happens inside the web view. However in **App Privacy** section I set that the app is collecting user information because of the cookies present on the web sites (Facebook Pixel, Google Ads, Analytics, etc..).

Now my questions are:

- Should I change the **App Privacy** information telling that app is not collecting information?
- I implemented the **App Tracking Transparency** framework. What should I do if the user refuses the tracking? Is it a transparent thing as the third party cookies will not be able to track users through the IDFA? Or should I interact in some way with the website to tell it that user did not allow tracking?

Comment: Some found some workaround like opening Safari outside app : [post on apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681464)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not my case. I need to stay inside the app

Answer (score 0):

You have declare it. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-privacy-details/#additional-guidance

> Your app has web views.
> Data collected via web traffic must be declared, unless you are enabling the user to navigate the open web.

By showing those WebViews your app IS collecting data (esp. if these are your "own" websites and not the "open web").
And it also reads like you can't display the website if the user did not comply to it or have another popup on the website itself.

> Collection of the data occurs only in infrequent cases that are not part of your app’s primary functionality, and which are optional for the user.

And, if I'm reading correctly, your app is just a wrapper around those websites.

Comment: My app is a wrapper around web site. The actual data collection happens on the website, no information is collected by the app directly. I still don't understand if I should specify or not if my app tracks user information

Comment: @giani.sim : be warned that Apple do not like app which are just web wrapper Ito one web site. Do you really need to go to others web site like Facebook which have their own app and user may open app upon web page open.

Comment: I know. In fact it is not just a wrapper. The webview is the main part which interacts with native components.

Comment: You are giving yourself the answer. Your webview is your primary view therefore there is no doubt about whether you need the tracking confirmation. If you’re lucky enough and your app provides enough functionality to be allowed into the app store in the first place. But of course you can always try and see what the reviewers of apple say. Since it’s something new we all can not give a definitive answer yet because there is a lack of experience.